# how to Select All words when a div focus using jquery 

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

this is my code :

```
<div id="box" style="border:1px solid red;height:100px;width:150px;position:relative;background:#eee">
        <div id="head" style="background:black">drag me</div>
        <div id="content" contenteditable=true style="border-bottom:1px solid red;height:70px;margin-bottom:5px;"> edit it </div>
        <input id="ok" type="button" value="ok"/>
        <input id="cancel" type="button" value="cancel"/>
    </div>
```

and the script is :

```
$('#content').focus()
```

the demo is here :http://jsfiddle.net/VRxZe/8/

how can i select 'edit it'

thanks

Comment: Haven't you already done that?

Comment: make the text like when i double click when it focus .

Comment: and like right click--> select all .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to select text inside some element, you can use Ranges. The code below should work with Firefox and Opera and Chrome. Another story is IE. For this browser you will have to [create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536401%28VS.85%29.aspx) new [TextRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535872%28VS.85%29.aspx) object and use its methods moveToElementText and select.

```
var content = document.getElementById('content');
var selection = window.getSelection();
var range = document.createRange();
range.selectNodeContents(content);
selection.removeAllRanges();
selection.addRange(range);
content.focus()
```

The code below is for IE

```
var content = document.getElementById('content');
var rng = document.body.createTextRange();
rng.moveToElementText(content);
rng.select();
content.focus()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: chrome sometimes cant select all .

Comment: Cannot reproduce this issue. What content do you have in this DIV? The "edit it" text or something else? Is this happening only in chrome? What version of chrome are you using? Mine is 9.0.587.0

Answer (score 2):

Well, you are almost there :)

```
  $('#box').focus(function()
           {
                $('#content', this).select();

           });
```

Comment: Is this correct? Doesn't this trigger a `select` event rather than actually selecting the element?

Comment: @Tim: If I'm not mistaken..   if the handler attached to the `select` event does not do a `e.preventDefault()` then the text would get selected.(i.e. default behaviour)